# Google Logged in React & Node .js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-google-login

I've search implementing logged in in a app with React js and a server with Node js and I found 2 different approachs to handling it.

1)Redirecting from the react app to the GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL that is defined on the backend and then receiving an url with the status and the jwt in case is logged in.

2)Using the library of react-google-login and with the clientId it will open automatically to logged in with google, and in the onSuccess event received the token, with that token called an endpoint to the backend so they can managed if that user already exist/or not in the database and response with the information needed.

Which of the 2 options is the correct one ?

Comment: OAUTH 2.0 is what you are looking for https://aaronparecki.com/oauth-2-simplified/

Comment: Why the 2 option is not the correct one ? That is the part I don;'t understand

Comment: in all cases out of respect for your end users you want to be security conscious, oauth is a battle tested industry standard with tons of documentation online of how to implement it and wont be going away very soon. In essence I think react-google-login is using oauth under the hood, so thats fine to use, however #2 looks to be a client only implementation of oauth, so you have a lot less control over what can be done on server side vs using the callback URL from option #1. #1 is definitely more difficult to implement (it took me like 5 days to figure it out in the beginning) but its worth it